# Nexus 6 file transfer over USB is not an option

Tags: file-transfer, usb-connection-mode, usb-mass-storage

I have a Nexus 6 (just factory reset).  When I connect it to my computer through USB, it charges, but nothing else.  My computer doesn't recognize any new device being plugged in, and my phone does not pop up with the dialog asking what I want to do (Charge, MTP, PTP, etc.), nor do I get a notification asking this, even when pulling down from the notification drawer.  I am running Android 6.0.  I have another Nexus 6, and it works fine.  When I plug the first Nexus 6 into any computer, I have the same issue, while the second device works fine in any computer.  I have tried Windows and Mac computers.

Comment: In developer options check *select USB configuration* is not set to *Charge only*

Comment: I did, I actually did another factory reset and haven't enabled developer options yet just in case that was part of the problem

Comment: But it was set to MTP before

Comment: I see. Possibly changing USB cable and checking may help

Comment: I have tried several usb cables, and no difference

Comment: The default setting on new devices is now always "Charge only". May be the device came with 5.1 (default setting MTP) and got an upgrade to 6 - therefore the setting was different before.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that the notification asking what mode I want does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You should try some of the following:

1. Make sure your phone is not encrypted. (Settings>Personal>Security>Encrypt Phone).
2. Try enabling USB debugging in dev settings and use `adb devices` and see if it is listed (you will obviously need adb).
3. Keep trying USB cables!
4. Try using something like ASUS File Manager to wirelessly transfer the files.
5. If they are photos you are trying to transfer, consider using Google Photos (accessible at drive.google.com)

Comment: 1. It is encrypted, but so is the other phone (the one that works).  However, I am trying pretty much everything now, so how do I decrypt it?
2. I have adb, and it is not listed
3. I will :P
4. I will look into this
5. It is not just photos, but also files and I want to flash an Android N image at some point

Comment: Nevermind apparently you can't decrypt without a factory reset.  Even though I did a factory reset it and it's still encrypted.  Hmm